# customize xml layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to make my search bar above my tabs but it appears behind it

[image]

This my xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.cloud.services.drmzr.MainActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.cloud.services.drmzr.MainActivity"
        android:layout_above="@+id/topBar">
        <include layout="@layout/user_search"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/topBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:background="@drawable/white_grey_border_bottom">


                </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>




        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_below="@+id/topBar"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottomBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/container"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        </RelativeLayout>





        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120px"
            android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/bottomNavView_Bar"
                android:background="@drawable/white_grey_border_top"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu">


            </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
        </RelativeLayout>



    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: What is inside your @layout/user_search?

Comment: That `CoordinatorLayout` setup isn't really correct. The `<AppBarLayout>` should be a direct child of the `<CoordinatorLayout>`. If you want the `<include>` vertically above the `<TabLayout>`, you can put it first thing inside the `<AppBarLayout>`. The `<ViewPager>` and `<BottomNavigationView>` should both be inside a single `<RelativeLayout>`, and that should have the `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` on it. Get rid of all of those nested `<RelativeLayout>`s.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, this is not the best layout. Very expensive to measure all relative layouts wrapped to each other. Your elements appear behind each other because you made your view in relative which is very similar to frame layout. I think a better way to do it in ConstraintLayout. But if you want to make it in relative do it like that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:background="@drawable/white_grey_border_bottom">
        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/user_search"
        android:id="@+id/user_search"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_below="@+id/user_search"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomNavView_Bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120px"
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavView_Bar"
        android:background="@drawable/white_grey_border_top"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>

</RelativeLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

place your search layout below tab layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.cloud.services.drmzr.MainActivity"
    android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout">
    <include layout="@layout/user_search"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

check this line : android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"